# Which Django model field goes with a CheckboxSelectMultiple form field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django form that allows a user to select multiple options:

```
CARDS = (
    ("visa", "Visa"),
    ("mastercard", "MasterCard"),
)

class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    credit_cards = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CARDS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    # ... etc.
```

I have the form's associated model setup as:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    credit_cards = models.CharField(choices=CARDS, max_length=100)
    # ... etc.
```

But I'm thinking that a CharField with the choices parameter can only accept a single choice because my form never validates and I get an error like:

**Value u"[u'visa']" is not a valid choice.**

And it sure looks like a valid choice.

I've seen that [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726476/django-multiple-choice-field-checkbox-select-multiple) get this working with a ManyToManyField on the model side (which I'd expect) but building a model just for a static list of credit card types seems overkill.

So: is there a specific model field type or different form configuration I should be using to support multiple selections from a pre-defined list of options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/

Comment: Thanks, I did see this snippet (probably should have mentioned that) but I figured that 2+ years later, the functionality would be built into django. Guess not.

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield which is inspired by that snippet