# Admin site add 2 related models at the same time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

So I have 2 models, like this:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    # some fields here

class MovieGenre(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=MOVIE_GRENRES)
```

This is my model admin:

```
class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'publish_date', 'file_1080p', 'thumbnail']
```

What I want to do is to let people add `Movie` models in the admin page, selecting the genres from the list (there are 6 genres) as a checkbox or something similar. So I don't create 2 different pages to add both movies and genres.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [Model Admin Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin):

> The admin interface has the ability to edit models on the same page as
>   a parent model.
>
> These are called inlines.

Example for [`TabularInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline):

```
from django.contrib import admin

class MovieGenreInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MovieGenre

class MovieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MovieGenreInline,
    ]
```

Comment: It is a choice field. Is it possible to use a checkbox for all genres instead of adding them from a dropdown?

Comment: @Pacha it really sounds like you need `ManyToManyField` here, not a simple `ForeignKey`. See this topic for a similar use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726476/django-multiple-choice-field-checkbox-select-multiple