# How to implement MultipleSelectionField m2m as a list rather than use a model?

Tags: python, django

[Django Multiple Choice Field / Checkbox Select Multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726476/django-multiple-choice-field-checkbox-select-multiple) Can this be implemented as a list rather than using a Choices model ?